# Load a data frame from the workspace using the name

Tags: r

So I've come across something that I thought would be easy but seem to be having a hard time with. I'm generating some tables in R (this part works fine). So let's say I have my tables:

```
df1 <- data.frame("col1" = 1:3, 
              "col2" = 5:7)

df2 <- data.frame("col1" = 10:12, 
                  "col2" = 22:24)

df3 <- data.frame("col1" = 5:7, 
                  "col2" = 9:11)
```

And I also have a vector with all the names of the tables:

```
names <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
```

Now I want to be able load these data frames in a for loop and assign them to a new value for some operations. The problem is I can't find a way to call them, using their names from the working space. I know I can write them in memory... smth like write.table(df1, "df1.rdata"), but I want to know if there is a way to avoid that. Something along the lines of:

```
for(i in names){
newdataframe <- get_from_workspace_function_by_name(i)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `?get`

Comment: Thanks. 

So eval(i) doesn't work.

get(i) seems to do the job tho :) .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to the comments I got the answer:

```
for(i in names){
newdataframe <- get(i)
}
```

Was quite sure there was an easy answer to this.